# In Redshift, how can I get an accurate insert count from stl_insert?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm attempting to get an insert count for a particular insert query using the following:

```
select sum(rows)
from stl_insert
where query=45441987;
```

query 45441987 is as follows:

```
insert into schema.table_name values
        (
            'value1'
            ,'value2'
            ,null
            ,null
            ,null
            ,null
            ,null
            ,null
        );
```

As you can see, I am inserting a single record into the table, but when I sum the rows from stl_insert, I get a total of 8. I'm assuming this is something to do with slice replication, but I just don't have the knowledge to fully understand what is happening here or how I can modify my code to get the correct result of 1 inserted record.

My one guess is to sum ( distinct rows ), but I imagine this would result in incorrect results when used for larger insert queries. I also tested if the 8 columns had any correlation to the sum of 8 returned by stl_insert, but changing the number of columns on my table had no effect on the returned insert count from stl_insert. Any advice?

The below table is the result of the following query:

```
select *
from stl_insert
where query=45441987;
```

| userid | query | slice | segment | step | starttime | endtime | tasknum | rows | tbl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 189 | 45441987 | 25 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.199086 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.202982 | 237 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 26 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.199160 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.202989 | 230 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 27 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.199262 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.202997 | 157 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 24 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.199024 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.497393 | 232 | 1 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.196361 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.200035 | 219 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.196458 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.200071 | 232 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.196539 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.200192 | 195 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.196308 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.502693 | 243 | 1 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 19 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.199540 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.203182 | 224 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 17 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.199337 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.203190 | 148 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 18 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.199419 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.203202 | 229 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 16 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.199293 | 2021-01-15 16:19:43.077544 | 237 | 1 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 13 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.196312 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.200170 | 151 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 15 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.196403 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.200174 | 251 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 14 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.196529 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.200189 | 233 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 12 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.196270 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.495647 | 178 | 1 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.198546 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.202014 | 155 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.198481 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.202047 | 136 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 7 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.198403 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.202067 | 217 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.198347 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.529713 | 207 | 1 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 9 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.197093 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.200558 | 180 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 10 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.197270 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.200562 | 191 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 11 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.196966 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.200675 | 162 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 8 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.196763 | 2021-01-15 16:19:43.002567 | 154 | 1 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 29 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.200823 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.204785 | 247 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 31 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.200904 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.204795 | 255 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 30 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.201022 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.204803 | 152 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 28 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.200770 | 2021-01-15 16:19:43.004712 | 150 | 1 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 22 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.196972 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.200493 | 208 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 21 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.196879 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.200499 | 217 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 23 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.196810 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.200503 | 213 | 0 | 13095244 |
| 189 | 45441987 | 20 | 2 | 2 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.196810 | 2021-01-15 16:19:42.541530 | 184 | 1 | 13095244 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you have 8 nodes of dc2.large in your cluster and the table is defined as DISTSTYLE ALL.  If so there are 8 inserts done, one per node, per the definition of the table.

Comment: This was definitely it! My table was actually set to DISTSTYLE AUTO, which set it to DISTSTYLE ALL behind the scenes. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Good to hear.  All the best.